How can you experience a visual image as an audio signal
Image below shows two different but geometric structures which I am trying to convert to audio signals which sound different. I have tried using each pixel as an oscillator and adding harmonics based on the values of surrounding pixels. I have also converted the square into a line of values then fed this into an fft. Results so far are poor.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EqnzUx8P6P3ivMllXNegcWdE_ESlIGhg/view?usp=sharing
Edit 8/10/24
Thank you for the helpful comments and links. I am digesting the handbook, wow. Whilst the SSFT looks appropriate it does have disadvantage of being an absolute technique whereas I am looking for a relative technique. By this I mean to define a sensing zone of n x m pixels and traverse the graphic through the zone from left to right, right to left or any defined trajectory. An empty zone is silent and as the graphic enters the zone audio builds until the complete graphic is completely in the zone. At this point the audio signal has a constant timbre and amplitude. If the sensing zone is larger than the graphic the signal is constant if the graphic is moved around inside the zone. Something like moving a tuning fork towards your ear, wiggling it around close to your ear and taking it away. Which ever way you do it the fork sounds the same. So I suppose I could see the example graphics as  two fancy tuning forks that have different timbres. I am following an assumption that to have a relative sonification technique requires the primary function of a pixel is to be an audio oscillator and I can produce some sounds with small sensing zones
example https://youtu.be/DKfAn2M_IAo
As I increase the size of the sensing zone the audio tends to be a mush tending to noise, it lacks a contrast or brilliance “button”. Maybe this is inevitable but I feel if I can see structure, no matter what its size, I should be able to hear this.
So why do I need this relative sonification technique? I generate some large terabyte 2D graphic structures and would like to play them as a musical instrument, moving one or  several sensing zones across the image. Ultimately defining the trajectory by a  dancer equipped with motion capture sensors and interfaced into the image with a virtual reality system.
Example of a larger graphic
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wat0TCXMVrxubpRUxBhFUol4QWxOqw6w/view?usp=drive_link
I have two simple images which I study
010   101
111   010
010   101
0 = no oscillator 1 = oscillator at frequency f. Both have 5 active oscillators, How to make them sound different?
Thanks again for you comments.

Try a STFT (Short Time Fourier Transform) where the spectrogram visualization of the magnitude is an image with the horizontal axis as time and the vertical axis as magnitude of the frequency.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform

What is your goal here? Do you want something that sounds "good"? do you want to be able to "recognize" the pictures? Is your primary motivation artistic of scientific ?

Well, the field of sonification is quite large and to my limited knowledge there are different ways people used various types of data to perform sonification. One of the possibly simplest and kind of straightforward is through STFTs like Dan Boschen suggested. You have to keep in mind though that not all data render themselves appropriate to all kinds of methods. I am not an expert when it comes to sonification but I would suggest the ”Sonification Handbook”
